# Slicing and skipping in Python

Tags: python

EDIT: I should be more clear. I really want to SKIP characters/letters, so not only solve the task of getting the first and last character to show. Even if I can do that by now. [::5] seems to work though.

I'm trying to slice a single word in python, so I'm given the first and the last letter. According to everything I read my code should be

```
word_ = "carrot"
letter = word_[0:6:4]
print(letter)
```

I understand it as the first 0 is the "c", the 6 is the "t" and the last 4 is how many characters you are skipping. The answer gives me "co". I have tried to experiment with my code but I only get the answer "co". Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong? I want the answer "ct"

Comment: `letter = word_[0:6:5]`

Comment: If `c` is `0`, then in what counting method is `t` `6`?

Comment: 4 is not how many character you want to skip, but the number of steps required to reach the next character of your choice. And `t` will be located at 5 not 6

Comment: FWIW, the most to the point solution using this particular approach is `'carrot'[::5]`…

Comment: Yes well, I get your point. I put the 6 down because I wasn't certain a "5" would be interpreted as "up to but not including" or not when I was trying to skip characters. However it doesn't seem to matter. 
Thanks for responses and code but I really would like to skip the letters in the middle. How should I go about that? 
Also Moses, I don't really get the difference.

Comment: You can omit both the start index and the end index entirely instead of using numbers you're unsure about (`[::5]`).

Comment: That helped, thank you! However, can you explain the syntax? I don't understand why it helped. Also, how do I mark a comment as the helpful answer haha.

Comment: Have you read the manual (including the notes)? https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-common

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Spaces included for readability*.

```
word = "c a r r o t"
#       0 1 2 3 4 5
#         _
#           _
#             _
#               _
#                 _
```

The first character is indexed at 0, the last at 5.

So you'll take 5 steps to reach the last starting from the first. But if you're going to include the last character in the slice, the stop parameter of the slice has to be one place ahead; since the stop index is usually not included.

So your slice is `[0:6:5] -> [start:stop:step]`. There are sleeker ways to get the first and last index viz. `[0]` and `[-1]`, or `[::len(s)-1]` but you can start with the former.

---

<sub>4 is not how many character you want to skip, but the number of steps required to reach the next character of your choice. And t will be located at 5 not 6</sub>

Comment: No, it doesnt work for some reason, I tried that and checked again now that you mentioned it. It should be reasonable but I just get "c".
[::5] solved it as I mentioned but I don't understand why haha.

Comment: Remember that your stop parameter is `6` not `5`. There was a typo on the slice: `[0:6:5]` not `[0:5:6]`

Comment: Ah that did the trick. So 6 is me telling python to exceed the last character, I get that. How does the step work though? I step all the way up to the character I want to use? Why not the one in front of it ([0:6:4)? I thought the step "took away" the characters I did NOT want to use.

Comment: No, not exactly the number of characters, but the number of *steps* to reach the last from the first, which is 5 here

Comment: I get it now! Thank you so much for taking your time:).

Answer (score 1):

Try this to print the first and last letters:

```
print word[0] + word[-1]
```

Or in python 3+ (as mentioned in comments)

```
print(world[0] + word[-1])
```

Comment: Looks like they're using Python3 but +1 otherwise

Comment: Good catch let me fix it

Comment: Already tried it and I get a traceback actually.
My code is 
word_ = "carrot"
then
letter = word_[0] + [-1]
then
print(letter)

Comment: @MrB Literally `word_[0] + [-1]`…? Why do you think that's the correct code?

Comment: Oh lord, yes it did. I was stupid and went "word_[0] + [-1]" and forgot that I ofc needed to have the word_ in front of the [-1] too. Thank you:). However, the question is still about me wanting to skip letters/characters if possible haha.

Answer (score 1):

Last parameter (4) is a step, that is symbol with indexes 0, 4, 8... are selected.

Answer (score 1):

python generally counts up elements in strings and list from zero to length of string.
So the 't' is at position 5, not 6.
You can step back by entering negative numbers, so you can get first and last character of a string like this.

```
word = "carrot"
first_letter = word[0]
last_letter = word[-1]
print(first_letter, last_letter)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ah, that code made more sense. However, if I would like to skip a step, that can be done right? Also, 5th or 6th step doesn't seem to matter since python just accepts the step as an "exceeding" step. The weird thing is I'm getting the "o" as the last character.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this instead:

```
word_ = "carrot"
letter = word_[0:6:5]
print(letter)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

If you really need to use `slice` in this specific case

```
word_ = "carrdote"
letter = word_[::len(word_)-1]
```

Edited as commented :P

Comment: `0` and `len(word_)` are really redundant, you can omit them entirely: `word_[::len(word_) - 1]`.

Comment: Edited. Can any of the downvoters give me a reason please?

Comment: Well I asked about slicing, maybe that's why haha.

Answer (score -1):

The equivalent `while` loop code of the slice notation for a string is:

```
>>> def slice(s, start, end, step):
...     result = ""
...     i = start
...     while i < end:
...             result += s[i]
...             i += step
...     return result
... 
>>> word = "carrot"
>>> slice(word, 0, 6, 4)
'co'
>>> word = "strawberry"
>>> slice(word, 0, 6, 4)
'sw'
>>> slice(word, 0, 9, 4)
'swr'
```

Comment: Quick downvoters, explain what's wrong with my answer

Comment: Maybe because the question was about slicing and your answer is totally unrelated.

Comment: @Matthias This answer is actually trying to explain what OP did wrong. Not *entirely* unrelated…

Comment: @Matthias Have you even read the question and my answer? OP does not understand slice notation. This is exactly the equivalent version of the slice operator with pure Python code.

Comment: @deceze: You're right. Mabe if it is explained better in the answer the downvotes will go.

Comment: @vz0: Obviously at the moment there are 4 posters who didn't understand what you were trying to explain.

Comment: @Matthias I never changed my answer and you quickly said "You're right". None of you actually read my answer.